# google maps how can i get live feed of a camera

Tags: google-maps, camera, feed, live

My requirement is, I have a set up of few IP cameras in a certain area. I have geo-location of each camera.All cameras are set-up in urban area. can I call these cameras on google-maps? is there any API for that ? i should get live feed, when I click on a particular camera .. Please help me

Comment: Your cameras are in no way connected to google maps.  If you wanted a live feed you would need them to broadcast a live stream over some network.

Comment: I you want to use Google Maps API, you'd better read some Google Maps API Docs.

Answer (score 0):

Google map not providing any API for controlling any type of hardware devices. If you want to control you have to set up everything yourself. Google map is an API for doing map or location operations like getting the latitude and longitude of a location, get the distance from one location to another, and a map view. In your case I don't think Google map can give any help.

You can start reading documentation of Google map from [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/https://developers.google.com/maps/?hl=en)

Comment: It seems, I can only provide url of a particular camera at each place mark... but it simply opens up new window in browser instead of open within maps application, where my purpose id defeated. any suggestions pl

Comment: I think I didn't understood

Comment: I mean to say that i can put a Placemark at each camera where i should provide URL(Since all cameras are public IP based). when user click on that short-cut of URL, It redirects to Camera's web page. but as i said purpose id defeated.all i am talking about on google-maps application only